# VBA - Compare absolute difference between column and one target cell

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to find the absolute difference between the value in `Cell C3` in `Sheet2` and the values in  `Col C` in `Sheet1`. After which, the differences are sorted in Descending order. The differences calculated will be inputted into column D. This is my code thus far, but it throws up an error at `Call Load`, `compile error. Argument not optional`. Can anyone help me to see what's wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Finding the absdiff:

```
Sub absdiff()

Dim i As Integer
Dim test As Range
Dim calc As Range

If Sheet1.Range("A:A") <> "" Then

Call Load

End If

Load:
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

test = Sheet2.Cells(3, 3).Value
calc = Cells(i + 1, "C").Value
Range("D" & i).Value = Abs(test - calc)

Next i

End Sub
```

Update sorting of column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Call absdiff

On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
Range("D").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), _
Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Call` to call another procedure - you are using it to point to a label. It looks redundant to me anyway -  just stick all that code in your If.

Comment: `If Sheet1.Range("A:A") <> "" Then` - is also wrong - you have to loop through the cells. (What is this line doing anyway?)

Comment: @SJR i tried putting the if statement before my For statement but an error popped up as well saying end if without block if. So i tried this method instead..That line is trying to say if there's a new entry i.e cells in column A is not empty, then find absdiff. Oh...that line says an error "type error mismatch"...

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Every time you put something in D the change event will be triggered, which doesn't seem like a desirable state of affairs.

Why not assign your code to a button instead?

Also, `test` and `calc` are values of cells, not range variables. I have changed to `Variant` but you could use `Long` or `Double` if you know they will be numbers.

---

Code re-jigged. I have put everything in the change event which is triggered whenever column C is changed. The issue before was that the other procedure was being called every time the sorting happened which caused an endless loop, hence out of stack space.

Your sort code was referencing an invalid range ("D") and sorting by B when I assume you want to sort by D.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long
Dim test As Variant
Dim calc As Variant

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
    test = Sheet2.Cells(3, 3).Value
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        calc = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "C").Value
        Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = Abs(test - calc)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A:D").Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), _
              Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
              OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hmm..it throws an error saying object variable or with variable not set at line `calc = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "C").Value` and i want the sorting to be updated everytime a new entry is entered in the worksheet hence the workbook change sub..

Comment: now it throws an "out of stack space error"..and "method value of object range failed" at ` Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = Abs(test - calc)` line

Comment: it still throws an "out of stack space error"..and "method value of object range failed" at `Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = Abs(test - calc)` line. It also ends up writing the value in my target cell value i.e. Cell C3, to my D1 cell

Comment: now there are no errors in the code but there are no absolute value differences in column D, weirdly..Cause the code doesnt look like its wrong..it looks right but its not working

Comment: Works for me. Go to the immediate window and type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and return.

Comment: omg i tried it out on a new excel workbook but its not working at all either

Comment: I've just thought of a new problem which is that if you sort every time you go through C you are changing the range so this approach really doesn't work. Needs a re-think.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = True` also doesnt work.

Comment: you know i actually wanted to do a normal excel absdiff between the cells but for example, if my target cell is 4,000, while my cell ranges are blank in col C, then it will return 4,000 which is not desirable since I only want to sort if there are actual inputs and not based on blank cells

Comment: Perhaps close this question and start again. Describe what you're doing and post a screenshot. There are quite a few errors in your current code and it's difficult to work out your precise set up.

Comment: sorry, the code u gave is able to work now but it writes the absdiff value to D1 instead of D2. Do you still want me to repost the qns?

Comment: Should it be `Sheet1.Range("D" & i+1).Value = Abs(test - calc)`? Why not just start the `i` loop at 2?

Comment: hmmm it seems to help the situation btr but whenever i have a new entry, the code overwrites the absdiff in the previous rows with my target cell value again which is 4,000.

Comment: Im not sure why everytime the cells in sheet 1 are blank, the 4,000 appears at cell D2

Comment: You could add a check that there is something in the cell before doing the calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far SJR..I reposted the question here, hopefully with more context..:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511457/vba-compare-absolute-difference-between-column-and-one-target-cell-after-whic