# How do I compare absolute difference between column and one target cell, and afterward, sort by Abs diff?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to create a scoreboard using VBA in Excel. When users click on the button to enter (See image below), they will key in their names, id and numeric answer in a user form (So 3 text boxes for them to fill up).

[image]

After the user clicks submit in the userform, the value should be saved in Sheet 1 for collation (take note of the 4,000 in `Cell D2`, more on it later):
[image]

This is the code for the userform:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Or TextBox3.Value = "" Then

 If MsgBox("Your details are not complete! Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
 Exit Sub
 End If
 End If

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = TextBox3.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Call resetform

End Sub
Sub resetform()

TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Only numbers are allowed"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

By right, when users click on the submit answer command button, the values will be saved accordingly in `Sheet1` with the code above.

However, my issue arises here now. I want to sort the values by absolute differences. I.e I want to compare all the numeric answers in `Col C` of `Sheet1`, to the target answer in `Cell C3` of `Sheet2`.:

[image]

After calculating the absolute differences, I want to sort the rows according to the absolute differences in Ascending order. This is the code for the sorting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim test As Variant
Dim calc As Variant

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    calc = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "C").Value
    test = Sheet2.Cells(3, 3).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "D").Value = Abs(test - calc)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A:D").Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Next i

End If
End Sub
```

However, when I clear my fields in `Sheet1`, the 4,000 in `Cell D2` appears. (I'm guessing it has to do with the 4,000 in the target answer minusing 0 since the fields are blank.) If I have new entries, and the difference is very huge, the sheet becomes messed up and looks like this: 
[image]

When I key in another number with a huge absolute difference, the 4,000 is repeated and the previous largest absolute difference is replaced with the new largest absolute difference value. Does anyone know why?

For @Mikku this is the latest error!:
[image]

Comment: First thing. Don't used `Activecell`, that's like calling Trouble. Use Direct References Instead like `Cells(1,1)` etc

Comment: @Mikku but im using activecell cause I want it to select the latest row, after the row where the user's data has been entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem. Looks like you are selecting any other cell before running the Userform, which in turn is the reason for those 2 blank rows. Try the Below and tell me if it's still happening.

**Change:**

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = TextBox3.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

**With:**

```
Dim last As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
.Range("A" & last + 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
.Range("B" & last + 1).Value = TextBox2.Value
.Range("C" & last + 1).Value = TextBox3.Value

End With
```

**Change the Worksheet Event Code to this: (Untested)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim test As Variant
Dim calc As Variant

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False


test = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 3).Value

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    calc = .Cells(i, "C").Value
    .Cells(i, "D").Value = Abs(test - calc)

Next i

    .Range("A:D").Sort Key1:=.Range("D2"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End With
End If
End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]

---

Updated Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim test As Variant
Dim calc As Variant

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim lst As Long
test = Worksheets("Target Answer").Cells(3, 3).Value

With Worksheets("Consolidation")
lst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lst

    calc = .Cells(i, "E").Value
    .Cells(i, "F").Value = Abs(test - calc)

Next i

    .Range("C2:F" & lst).Sort Key1:=.Range("F3"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to sort on basis of column D ? But in the Image you data is sorted pretty fine. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: yes :) but currently its messed up, as seen in the last image..my only problem is with the sorting but I thought it would be good to show the whole issue to let people know the flow of my problem

Comment: @psyduck .. in the Image Column D is in Ascending Order. I Don't see anything wrong with it. Not able to understand what you mean by **Messed up**

Comment: By messed up i mean, the 4,000 isnt supposed to be there to begin with (look at image 2). I dont want the 4,000 to be there at all. I think it has to do with the blank cells (which possibly equals to 0) where 4,000 - 0 equates to 4,000 in `Cell D2`. I'm not sure why the 4,000 keeps adding on to the list if the difference in absolute value is alot (as seen in the last image). I tried your code but there are errors popping up where "End with without with" or "End if without if" I tried moving the Withs and Ifs around but the error still pops up

Comment: That's why I asked you to change the `Activecell`. Clear your sheet one and using the changes I mentioned run it again from start. @psyduck .. Let me check my code again

Comment: @psyduck .. One End With was Missing . I have added that now.

Comment: ah...it is able to run now but now there's another issue...I'll add the image as the last image in my post so that you can see what the problem is!

Comment: Mikku, I've added in the new image, its throwing up a new 0 in my column D whenever I have new entry coming in

Comment: @psyduck .. Do you cancel your Userform or Select No in Msgbox ?

Comment: nope i didnt, I didnt even close the userform window, i kept entering and submitting before closing the userform and then checking my collation sheet after that

Comment: Can you share the File ?

Comment: oh how do i do that here?

Comment: @psyduck .. I think I spotted the Issue. It as in the Loop of your Worksheet_change  event. I have corrected it in the Answer. Try again with the new code. If it still doesn't work, share your file using One drive, google drive or any other sharing service

Comment: @psyduck ... Try the latest Worksheet Change Code, It will Work. :) Accept & Upvote the Answer

Comment: indeed!! It works now, thank you so much Mikku, Pure genius!!!!!!! And I'm sorry for taking up your time! And how the heck did you add in that demo!!! It's so cool!!

Comment: hi Mikku, I'm so sorry to bother you again, revisions were made to the workbook. Column A is intentionally left blank, and this time I'm trying to add a serial number to column B whenever a user submits a form. The serial number shouldn't be sorted but I only want to sort the name, email and answer column. I tried, and this is my new workbook.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GEKWkLz-kNFIhUK7n66JGtT2tnIh9-Kl

Comment: @psyduck .. Use the updated Code. Also if you have any other issue, please post a new question. :)

Comment: Sorry Mikku, the same issue still arises..I put up the updated file in the link.. I was thinking to post a new thread but I thought it would be better here cause you know the issue best. sorry:(

Comment: @psyduck  .. It's working (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AVXo5xkaXvpgmZHrTtGaSYTO-GLzA9y_)

Comment: ah..but the no. col in col B doesnt work:( the code is found in the command button of the userform..and it gives an error saying "out of memory" when i run the userform

Comment: @psyduck .. Delete that Loop, And another line with the rest `.Range("B" & last + 1).Value = last - 2`

Comment: that worked thank you:) my absolute difference column still doesnt work and it runs into the same error..i uploaded the image of the error on the drive and the latest workbook..

Comment: @psyduck ... [See this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OmQ6YbhwKiOEKrqDMKhoftXT0F4WOJJG)

Comment: yes yours seem to work...but mine keeps running "out of memory error" even when i try it on your workbook :( see my latest screenshots https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GEKWkLz-kNFIhUK7n66JGtT2tnIh9-Kl

Comment: Not sure why it's happening @psyduck .. Post a New question. Maybe someone will know why.

Comment: Thank you Mikku, it all seems to work now after closing all my excel programmes and only opening that workbook...which is strange. Thank you for all your help tho, you're nice and you have a vast amount of knowledge on vba :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198103/discussion-on-answer-by-mikku-how-do-i-compare-absolute-difference-between-colum).